# Use custom normalizer to modify class properties

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I have an entity with 2 properties, `name` and `photo`.  The `name` property is read from the database but I have to fill the `photo` property with some other information.

I have followed the **[Writing a Custom Nomalizer](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/content-negotiation#writing-a-custom-normalizer)** tutorial from the docs and I have made my custom normalizer:

```
<?php

namespace App\Serializer;

use App\Entity\Style;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\DenormalizerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\NormalizerInterface;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Templating\Helper\UploaderHelper;

final class StyleNormalizer implements NormalizerInterface, DenormalizerInterface
{
    private $normalizer;

    private $uploaderHelper;

    public function __construct(NormalizerInterface $normalizer, UploaderHelper $uploaderHelper)
    {
        if (!$normalizer instanceof DenormalizerInterface) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('The normalizer must implement the DenormalizerInterface');
        }

        $this->normalizer = $normalizer;
        $this->uploaderHelper = $uploaderHelper;
    }

    public function denormalize($data, $class, $format = null, array $context = [])
    {
        return $this->normalizer->denormalize($data, $class, $format, $context);
    }

    public function supportsDenormalization($data, $type, $format = null)
    {
        return $this->normalizer->supportsDenormalization($data, $type, $format);
    }

    public function normalize($object, $format = null, array $context = [])
    {
        if ($object instanceof Style) {
            $object->setPhoto('http://api-platform.com');
        }

        return $this->normalizer->normalize($object, $format, $context);
    }

    public function supportsNormalization($data, $format = null)
    {
        return $this->normalizer->supportsNormalization($data, $format);
    }
}
```

But the `photo` property is not filled with the required information.

After a little bit of debug I have found that the `supportsNormalization` method is executed two times (for each database element). If I print the `$data`variable, I got the entity `name` property the first time and the `photo` property with `null` value the second time. I never got the entire `Style` entity. Then the `supportsNormalitzation` method always returns `false`.

How can I get the full `Style` entity and modify its properties?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this to your `supportsNormalization` methods :

```
public function supportsNormalization($data, $format = null)
{
    return
        $this->normalizer->supportsNormalization($data, $format)
        && is_object($data) && $data instanceof Style::class
        ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It still not working... If I add a `var_dump($data)` it only prints a string with the `name` property content and null for the `photo` property...It never prints the full `Style`entity

Comment: Ok, I've seen that It only works if I use `json` format (not for `json-ld` and other formats)

Comment: If you want works with json-ld you have to decorate specific api platform normalizer : `decorates: 'api_platform.jsonld.normalizer.item' `
OR for json `decorates:'api_platform.jsonapi.normalizer.item'`
`

Comment: Yes nice! thats what I was looking for!